# State Object structure changed

Tags: javascript, object, reactjs, redux

I´ve written a small toDo-list app with Database interaction. Everything works fine, except that when I try to remove a toDo-list item from my state, the object-state structure is changed. 
Therefore I´m not longer able to render my ToDo-list on runtime.

I assume that just a small change in my reducer code is required, but I´m a little bit to experienced with ES6 & Redux to get it on my own.

This is my Reducer Code:

```
export default (state = {items: []}, action) => {
switch (action.type){
    case 'RECEIVE_POSTS':
        return Object.assign({}, state, {
            items: action.items
        });
    case 'ADD_ITEM':
        return Object.assign({}, state, {
            items: [
                ...state.items,
                action.items
            ]
        });
    case 'REMOVE_ITEM':
        return Object.assign({}, state, {
            items: [
                state.items.filter((items, id) => id !== action.id)
            ]
        });
    default:
        return state
    }
   }
```

And my deleteItem - Action

```
export default function deleteItem(id){
console.log("test")
return (dispatch, getState) => {
    return dispatch (removeItem(dispatch, id))
    return dispatch (receiveDelete(id))
   }
 }

 function removeItem(dispatch, id){
   return dispatch => {
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost:444/localWebServices/removeTask.php",
        data: {id: id}
    }).success(function(msg){
        console.log(msg)
        dispatch(receiveDelete(id))
    });
    }
   }

  function receiveDelete(id){
   console.log("receive add")
   return {
    type: 'REMOVE_ITEM',
    id: id
    }
   }
```

And Here a two Images of the Object Structure before and after I deleted an Item.

To make this clear. Everything works (the list is rendered), but after I deleted an Item the State structure is changed -> List not rendered. I don´t get any Error msg.

Before delete:

[image: State Before Delete]

After delete:

[image: State After Delete]

Any help would be great!

Update:

I have changed my Code and do not return an array anymore. According to the dev console the state seems to be correct now, but it´s not rendering. Does this code goes in the right direction?

```
return Object.assign({}, state, {
            items: state.items.filter((items, id) => id !== action.id)
        });
```

Comment: So on deletion you're adding **all the current** items **plus** an array of items that don't match by id?

Comment: So how are you supposed to learn anything if you don't code?

Comment: Well, it does not work (and the further you go - the less efficient your path will be).

Comment: So what kind of answer you expect then? Do you want someone to write code for you that you would be able to copy-paste?

Comment: I have given a hint in my very first comment. Another hint: what is the type of `state.items` after you perform removal?

Comment: It actually looks good now. What "not rendering" exactly means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arguments passed to filter callback are `arrayElement, index, array` so try changing your callback to `.filter(item => item.id !== action.id)`